# EJB: Dependency injection without Interface

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb

I had this code

```
@Local  
interface IRepo  
{  //...  
}  

@Stateless  
class Repo implements IRepo  
{  // ..  
}  

class WebS  
{  
@EJB private IRepo repo;  
// ...  
}
```

And all worked normally.

But now I remove interface  `IRepo` and make

```
@Stateless  
class Repo     {  // ..  
}  

class WebS  
{  
@EJB private Repo repo;  
// ...  
}
```

and JNDI look up fails.

```
could not resolve global JNDI name for @EJB for container WebS ...
```

Can I make Dependency injection without Interface?

Comment: Map your Repo class with @LocalBean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean // <-- annotation here
class Repo     {  
}  

class WebS  
{  
@EJB private Repo repo;  
// ...  
}
```

*Make sure you use EJB-3.1-compliant application server*

Comment: It's true, but I am using 3.0. In 3.0 Interface is requared

Comment: Then what's the question?

Comment: But if a `LocalBean` is a session bean, then doesn't that conflict with `Stateless`? The API seems to indicate that it can't be `Stateless`, unless I'm misinterpreting what they're getting at with a 'session bean'.