# Is it possible to inject an EJB bean by class type rather than interface type

Tags: java, interface, ejb, enterprise, inject

The problem is: I have some class that extends the java.util.Observable and implements java.util.Observer at the same time. I know about @LocalBean annotation, but this solution doesn't suit me because I need to use the Class both ways as a class and as an interface. Is there something that can helps me to resolve my problem?

```
    public class SomeClass extends Observable implements Observer {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: What version of Java are you on?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10499381/11780044. It discusses how to use the injection with/without an interface and displays how he used it before with the new "non" interface manner.

Comment: You need to show more code demonstrating what you are trying to do